# JBoss portal with an existing application

Tags: spring, jboss, portal, jboss-portal

I have never worked with portals before. So I am confused now. We have an application which is working with Spring and tomcat 5.5. So now they are telling me to use JBoss portal on top of that. My question is that is it possible to link my application which is already done with jsp, spring, etc to the JBoss portal. When I want to install JBoss portal as options it has JBoss7 and tomcat 6 options. This wouldn't interfere with my own app which has to run on tomcat 5.5. Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is with [JSR 329](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=329) which allows to bridge JSF1.2 applications with [JSR 286](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286) based portal environment. The JBoss implementation of JSR 329 called [JBoss Portlet Bridge](http://www.jboss.org/portletbridge) gives you the flexibility to run SEAM as well in portal environment without knowing the details of the portal technology. In addition to this, you can also explore Spring's [Portlet MVC Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/portlet.html) but the limitation with this framework is your portlet implementation would be in [JSR 168](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168) style which is earlier/base version of portlet specification. Another option for you is to develop a separate portal application with portlets calling your business layer services directly to get the work done. I am not aware about any other frameworks/technology you can use to run spring applications in portal environment. And so go ahead with detailed requirement analysis session with your team and identify how they really want the portal to function.

Comment: Thanks Mod. So is that bridge only for JSF app? We are using JSP. Thanks.

Comment: Portlets are like any other Controller governing execution flow to render views (dynamic content in your jsp) as per business logic for a web application, only difference being portal container can stitch together views rendered from several different portlets (deployed on a portal page) into a single html which is then sent across to the client browser. Imagine iGoogle as a page with a number of individual web applications deployed, each designed to interact with users with a defined UI/view(jsp). But together they are rendered as a single html page. [read more](http://manning.com/sarin/)

Comment: I suggest you try out a simple portlet using Spring Portlet MVC framework, in case you find your application can be migrated using the framework then go for it because technically speaking bridge is meant for JSF applications, although I have not tried to bridge a spring application myself. May be you could teach me about it once you are through with this exercise.